# bash скрипт работает не корректно

Tags: linux, qt, bash

Имеется скрипт:

```
#!/bin/bash
touch /etc/test/bkl
chmod 777 /etc/test/bkl
echo 152b3f9f45bcd2592930b6474aede922 > /etc/test/bkl
chmod 644 /etc/test/bkl
ldconfig
rm $1/ins.sh
```

Если построчно копировать в терминал то все нормально(создается файлик,и заполняется).Но если запускать скрипт(запускаю через `qtif`) то происходит билиберда.

```
-rw-r--r--   1 root root     0 сен 12 16:58 bkl
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    33 сен 12 16:58 bkl?
```

Почему создается два файла , и заполняется файл с вопросом на конце?
Открывал скрипт через `cat`.Все нормально,кодировка не сбита

Comment: попробовал твой скрипт запустить из файла, всё работает без проблем.
так что смотри что там у тебя за `qtif`

Comment: *Useless use of touch*. `>` создаст файл. Права 0777 непонятны. Зачем? Права 0644 тоже непонятны. Используете `umask`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Похоже что у вас в `echo ... >` в конце имени файла невидимый юникодный символ...

Comment: а ещё могут быть виндовые концы строк...

Answer (score 2):

Заключите имена файлов в кавычки. Идеально -- сделать переменной, чтобы не печатать одно и то же много раз, повышая вероятность ошибки. Как-то так:

```
#!/bin/bash
FNAME="/etc/test/bkl"
touch "$FNAME"
chmod 777 "$FNAME"
echo 152b3f9f45bcd2592930b6474aede922 > "$FNAME"
chmod 644 "$FNAME"
ldconfig
rm $1/ins.sh
```

Кавычки нужны везде на случай, если в имени файла и/или пути будут пробелы.

Answer (score 1):

`test@test:/# bash -x /file/test.sh`  **"Debug"**
В подарок )))